# TypeError while template matching in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, typeerror, template-matching

Part of my code is :

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
img=ImageGrab.grab()
img = img.load()
img = np.array(img)
template = cv2.imread('s2_5.jpg',0)
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "E:\python\opencv\template_matching.py", line 20, in <module>
  res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
TypeError: image data type = 17 is not supported
```

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because `img` and `template` are not of the same type, and more importantly, as the error messages says, `img`'s type is not supported by [`cv2.matchTemplate()`](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html).

On line 20 of your code, `ImageGrab.grab()` returns a PIL/Pillow image. So you need to convert `img` to a numpy array before using it as an input of `cv2.matchTemplate()`.

Comment: On line 4, I converted that image to numpy array. `img = np.array(img)`

Comment: @rajinikanth convert explicitly to `uint8`.

Comment: now i got this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\opencv\template_matching.py", line 14, in <module>
    img = np.array(img,dtype=np.uint8)
TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'PixelAccess' `